# Using key, value pairs to update Models in peewee?

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

Is there a way to programmatically update Models using key, value pairs in peewee? I have been trying to do it by iterating through **kwargs, using the following code:

```
for key, value in kwargs.items():
    if value is not None:
        self.physician.update(key=value)
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'RequestDetail' has no attribute 'key'
```

Is there any way to get the update() method to accept the key argument as the value of 'key' instead of interpreting it literally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
self.physician.update({key:value}).execute()
```

Putting it in a dict might just do the trick, you can also do

```
self.physician.update(kwargs).execute()
```

Since kwargs is also a dict but ofcourse you still need to remove the values that are None first